# What is the "Menu Title" for the shortcut to jump to a browser tab by number?

Tags: macos, keybindings

In my previous machine, I was able to jump to a tab using its position. Alt-2 gets me to the 2nd tab.. so on. On macOS, I had to swap "option" and "command" keys due to muscle memory.

I need to add App Shortcuts under Brave Browser in macOS Keyboard customisation, which needs the "Menu Title". What is the "Menu Title", say for jumping to tab 2 ?

By default, the jump to tab is bound to "command" prefix. So cmd-2 will get me to tab 2. But I need to know the "Menu Title" to which it is bound.

[image: Customisation Window]

[image: Add shortcut popup]

Answer (score 1):

It's not bound to a menu item, so you can't change it.

Swapping the modifier functions or positions always leads to conflicts & confusion. Long term it's better to just learn the difference. [Speaking as someone who's been using Macs for over 30 years & Windows for about 20.]

Comment: I appreciate the tip.. but as I still frequently use my previous machine it would be more confusing if i did not swap the modifiers.

Comment: That's what everybody says for the first couple of years. Long-term, it's better to learn the difference than try fight it. Anyway, what you want cannot be done.